# Free recipes API returning XML, without HTTP headers

Tags: api, xml, recipes

I need a recipe api with the following prefrences:

- Needs to be in xml
- Has a free version
- Headers should not be required/ api key should be in url

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Similar but not in XML: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/20983/754